# Could not reserve enough space for object heap when running JUnit tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

In my project I have unit tests. I am using IntelliJ. Whenever I try to run them, IntelliJ shows message:

> Error occured during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

I tried to run those tests with VM arguments `Run Configuration -> VM options: -Xms256m -Xmx512m`
I have read a lot about this problem (and proposed solutions), tried many combinations, but none of them worked. I became frustrated and thought that my test is "too complicated" (mocks and things like that...), so I have written sample test:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I am still getting the same error! Problem occurs **only when running tests** - other methods run fine. Any ideas what may cause this strange and annoying error? I am new to IntelliJ, so maybe I am missing something.

**UPDATE**

I tried to run the tests from command line, but with the same result. Finally I was able to run them,  by adding `-DforkMode=never` to maven command. But still not able to run test(s) from IntelliJ.

Comment: Perhaps your system is out of memory?

Comment: It would be strange. I have 3GB of RAM, almost 2GB is free. Also I mentioned, that other methods run smoothly, only tests have this error. And sample test I am trying to run is not very expensive in memory I think...

Comment: Problem is you machine cannot start a VM. I suggest you restart you machine and try.

Comment: But it starts other (including complex) Java programs, so IntelliJ is able to start VM. It only has problems with tests.

Comment: I wonder if something is setting a `ulimit` ...

Comment: I am using Windows and as far as I know there is no `ulimit`. I don't know how much heap space it needs to just run test, but I guess it is less than some complex Java application which in fact I am able to run.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue which is now resolved for me. If you are using maven, you can configure the default jvm args or other test options that need to be passed to the runs by adding similar properties like this to your `pom.xml`. You might want to note that this is kind of a master setting for all you junit runs.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xms500m -Xmx1g</argLine>
                <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In my case, project had this configuration set to use `-Xms10g -Xmx10g`. Replacing this with lower values like `-Xms500m -Xmx1g` fixed the issue.

You might already have a similar configuration so you may want to override it locally, else adding this configuration should help override the default values passed by Intellij.